# BrowserComponent WKWebView or UIWebWiew on IOS13.4 hangs on "executeAndReturnString"

Tags: codenameone

Is there a bug in browserComponent on IOS 13.4?

When I execute this command on WKWebWiew the App Hangs.

```
String userAgent = browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("navigator.userAgent");
```

On Android works fine.

Regards

Comment: I added a sample for this, and it seems to work fine on iOS 13.3 and 13.4 (iPhone 6S).  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Samples/samples/ExecuteAndReturnStringTest/ExecuteAndReturnStringTest.java

Try modifying that sample to reproduce the hanging.

Comment: Hi, I be able to reproduce the issue, fails when we set the property BrowserComponent.useWKWebView to true. 
   
Display.getInstance().setProperty("BrowserComponent.useWKWebView", "true");

BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();

Display.getInstance().setProperty("BrowserComponent.useWKWebView", "false");

ToastBar.showInfoMessage("navigator.userAgent:" + browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("navigator.userAgent"));

Then the App hangs on IOS, tested on 13.4, 12.4 and 13.3 fails on all of then.

Comment: If you remove the `Display.getInstance().setProperty("BrowserComponent.useWKWebView", "false");` line, does it work for you?